# C# - Having problems using web browser for scraping

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I have been trying to make a web scraper tool to get all the pastebin urls using the bing search engine.

I managed to do that by using web browser and letting the javascript run and then scraping all the source.

```
string attempt = ""
```

^
I got 2 problems. the first problem is if I don't write the line `MessageBox.Show(this.attempt)` the variable will be empty for some reason. another problem is for now I get only 9 links and it doesn't download the other pages like it should be. I think it's all because of the `MessageBox.Show(this.attempt)` thing.

I know my code is not the best and probably there are a lot of much better ways but I would like to get help to understand what's going on here.

Thank you very much

here is my code:

```
private void Scan(Label pages)
        {
            string regex = @"https:\/\/pastebin.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+";
            for (int i = 1; i <= Config.Amount_Of_Pages; i++)
            {
                Parse(i);
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(this.attempt, regex);
                MessageBox.Show(this.attempt);
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    Config.List_Of_Urls.Add(match.Value.ToString());
                    Config.List_Of_Urls = Config.List_Of_Urls.Distinct().ToList();
                }

                Config.Amount_Of_Pages_Scanned++;
                pages.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { pages.Text = Config.Amount_Of_Pages_Scanned.ToString(); }));
                Files.Write_Urls(Config.List_Of_Urls);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }

        private void Parse(int i)
        {
            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.DocumentCompleted += Wb_DocumentCompleted;
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            wb.Navigate("https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3apastebin.com++email%3apassword&first=" + i);
        }

        private void Wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var wb = (WebBrowser)sender;

            var html = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].OuterHtml;

            this.attempt = html.ToString();
            /* ... */
        }
```

Comment: the reason the messagebox makes it work is becuase the web brwoser control will take some time to navigate to that URL. THe MessageBox call slows your code down.

Comment: I thought it could be the problem, however I used for loop because I have an options to choose how many pages I would like to scrape and the first time I can see the Messagebox show but after the loop finish and another round starts I cannot see the messagebox show again so it's like skipping it and just doing the same parsing to the same HTML code again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I prefer to use [Selenium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops) and suggest it for you.
2. If you want to get distinct urls, you should use [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) instead of List.
3. You should add optional part `(www\.)?` to regex.
4. To handle retry policy, I prefer to use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#wait-and-retry)

The result code is:

```cs
RetryPolicy retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
    .WaitAndRetry(new[]
    {
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
    });

string regex = @"https:\/\/(www\.)?pastebin.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+";
HashSet<string> sites = new HashSet<string>();

retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
{
    using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3apastebin.com++email%3apassword&first=1");
        // We have to wait until the page will download and rendered in the browser.
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(driver.PageSource, regex))
        {
            sites.Add(match.Value);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I know about Selenium the problem is I would like to add Threads and make the program run faster and using multiple drivers will do hard life to the Computer I think. you know maybe why my code does those 2 problems I wrote?

Comment: I think, if you parse Bing with multiple thread Bind will block you. Do you have any plans to use proxy?

Comment: I made a project like this long time ago. when I did it I could just use WebClient and it worked great but now I can't because I need to wait for the java script to load. when I did it before I could use 100 threads and bing never blocked me

Comment: I just don't understand why without the messagebox it won't work and even with messagebox why it works only the first time the loop start and the rounds after it won't work

Comment: Ok. Method `WebBrowser.Navigate` is asynchronous. It means that we have to wait some time, when page will be downloaded. You should to synchronize with `ManualResetEvent` instead of using `MessageBox`. Now you are trying to parse html that was not uploaded yet.

Comment: I chose to use Selenium, it works great and the speed is ok as well. thank you very much :)

one more question, I could use threads to run a few drivers at the same time right? like 3 drivers shouldn't make hard life for the computer

Comment: I think that it would be ok.